# Unexpected @Html.HiddenFor() behaviour in asp.net 4.5.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have some strange behaviour with a `@Html.HiddenFor()` helper and was wondering if this was by design?

There's an id field that takes essentially a `Guid` string value for a booking form, naturaly before a user has booked this value is null/empty, and is stored in a hidden field.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BookingId) 
//Renders correctly as:  
<input type="hidden" name="BookingId" value />
```

When posting this form via ajax, the booking id is generated and returned with the form in the model and stored again with the exact same hidden field. I can verify `model.BookingId` has the value assigned however when I check the value of the hidden field it is *still null*?

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BookingId)
//Renders incorrectly as:
<input type="hidden" name="BookingId" value />
//It should be
<input type="hidden" name="BookingId" value="The booking id here" />
```

Here's the kicker, I change the html helper to this and it works as expected...

```
<input type="hidden" name="BookingId" value="model.BookingId" />
```

What gives?

**Edit: It is in fact by design**

@Phong Nguyen's left a link in the comments to his post below that shows the logic and what is happening in the model binding process.